# Does SQL Server automatically allocate memory to all instances?

Tags: sql-server

I have a single instance of SQL Server on my server machine, with 80% of the memory reserved to it. This is configured in the SQL Server max memory settings.

If I create an additional instance, will it use the reserved memory, or will it attempt to use the unallocated 10%?

Simply put, is the reserved memory used by SQL Server instance specific?

Comment: yes. also remember that you need some spare room for the OS and any other processes running, so if you want two instances running on the same maching, I'd recommend lowering the memory of the existing to allow room for the second.

Comment: Also see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba. Each server instance is just a program that will compete with every other program running on the machine. You need to set reasonable limits for min and max based on the demand usage of each instance as well as your performance goals.

Comment: SQL Server instances behave completely independently. They share no settings at all and are largely unaware of each other (by design). There are some services that are installed only once per machine (Browser, Integration Services) but aside from that there's no overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Max and Min Server Memory are NOT reservations. It does not work the same way as e.g. VmWare with reservations.

On startup, the instance only uses a minimum amount of memory - it does not grab the Min Server Memory amount immediately.

In normal use, your instance will continue to use more memory as required until it reaches the Max Server Memory limit - but only if there is no external memory pressure signalled by Windows. If the system requests more memory, SQL Server will release this but will not release if it would drop below Min Server Memory.

Therefore if you are going to install more than 1 instance - you need to be careful in regards to the Min Server Memory and not set this so high that the sum of all Min Server Memory amounts plus the amount needed by the OS and other programs is more than the total physical memory available.  Also think about what is realistic for the Max Server memory - as one instance increases memory uses it may request other instances to release some memory back - possibly impacting performance of other instances.

You'll need to monitor what your instance actually needs - counters such as Page Life Expectancy can help give you an idea of how long pages stay in memory after loaded (i.e. is there memory pressure) which will help you identify the impact of lowering Max Server Memory for that instance.

The performance characteristics of each database will affect what you configure.

In saying that, in these days of virtualisation - I would tend to avoid multiple instances per server and simply spin up another VM for my new instance. That way I can have more control over the actual physical reservations for memory - but I still need to be aware of operations like ballooning if I over-allocate.